# jQuery/JS/CSS3 animations and hover effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have been struggling for a some days now and it seems I can't figure out how to make such hover animations. Perhaps I dig in the wrong place and the animations are done with css3.

Anyway, that site particularly has the animations I am looking for but when I go through it's code I can't find the answer.

[Brushed](http://themes.alessioatzeni.com/html/brushed/)

The image hover effects do look like a normal css3 hover animation, but what really intrigued me was the 
mobile-version of the navigation button, animating from an align-justify icon to a cross icon.

Anything would be helpful even just a hint in which direction should I keep on looking. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not much since I couldn't find the answer inside of the web-sites code and I am still unsure how the animations were created.

If they were with CSS3 my guess would be with the transform property because both animations come in an angle (but it would require a lot of code to animate them in such a smooth manner), but the next question would if it has been created with jQuery, does jQuery .css() work with css3s transform property ?

Comment: ok please explain all things in detail like you are developing which kind of application with which technology and you want these animations where?

Comment: @himanshu hinted to use pseudo-classes to animate certain things - so that's the answer I have been looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is done by using `:before` and `:after` . when clicked they rotate and change position....

Comment: That's it, thank you very much! So they were pure css3 animations not jQuery as I thought before.

Comment: yes it is pure css3 effect and i think if you look properly on that site you also get its tutorials

Comment: Thats not an answer You are fooling people around.@himanshu

Comment: how can you tell me i did understand what you mean @sagar43

Comment: Just wait i flagged your answer too, wait for the stackoverflow community to take action.

Comment: i am just asking what i did wrong

Comment: @sagar43 wait, this answers question even this kind of question should not been answered imho